# Java program - password checker

Tags: java

I need to write a program that takes a password in string form as input.

I had to make an array with 15 of the most common passwords I could think of, ensuring that none of these common passwords are contained within the users password. I have tried more than a few options but most just returned an error message stating something like "String index is out of range."

Here is my most recent attempt.

```
for(int i = 0; i < commonPass.length; i++) 
{
  if (password.indexOf(commonPass[i]) > 0) 
  {
    System.out.println("Enter new password.");
    password = kb.nextLine();
  }
}
```

My knowledge of java is fairly basic so any help offered would be much appreciated.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
String index out of range: 8 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source) at PasswordProgram.main(PasswordProgram.java:95)
```

Comment: Stack trace please :)

Comment: I'm assuming you mean this: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 8
 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
 at PasswordProgram.main(PasswordProgram.java:95)
As I said my knowledge is very basic. :L

Comment: Note that if the two passwords match/the `password` begins with the `commonPass[i]` then `indexof()`will return 0, so it should be >=0

Comment: the stack trace means that in line 95 of your PasswordProgram file, you called charat() and passed it 8. however, the string in question was only 7 or fewer characters long hence the error

Comment: @vandale not really, the `charAt` call was made by a method implementation of the Java API (because of the `Unknown Source` part returned). Dear new user, could you indicate the line where the exception was thrown next? As we cannot see the line numbers.

Comment: @owlstead the `Unknown Source` is the location where the exception was thrown in the `charAt()` function.

Comment: see my answer... tested and works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the contains function to check if the string contains that piece of string.

```
for(int i = 0; i < commonPass.length; i++) 
{
  if (password.contains(commonPass[i])) 
  {
     System.out.println("Enter new password.");
     password = kb.nextLine();
  }
}
```

From the Java docs (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api):

contains(CharSequence s) : Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values.

I have tested the following code and that should work correctly. Good luck programming!

```
private void CheckPassword()
{
    String[] commonPass = new String[4];
    commonPass[0] = "testing";
    commonPass[1] = "stackoverflow";
    commonPass[2] = "coding";
    commonPass[3] = "userinput";

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your password.");
    String password = s.nextLine();

    for(int i = 0; i < commonPass.length; i++) 
    {
        if (password.contains(commonPass[i])) 
        {
            CheckPassword();
        }
    }       

}
```

Comment: While the idea is right, but this code will have to be modified so that when user input a new password, you have to check all the password in the commom password array again.

Comment: Thnx for pointing that out. Added some extra code that fixes that.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks to everyone who gave input. Awesome website, with awesome people. I'll definitely be returning if I need any help.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go..

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Password {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean wrongpassword= true;

    ArrayList<String> knownPasswordList = new ArrayList<String>();

    knownPasswordList.add("password1");
    knownPasswordList.add("password2");
    knownPasswordList.add("password3");
    knownPasswordList.add("password4");

    String password = "";

    do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter New Password");
password = kb.nextLine();
    }while(knownPasswordList.contains(password));

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This should work. See if this helps -

```
String[] commonPassword = {"pass1","pass2"}
ArrayList<String> passwordList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(commonPassword));
String password = "";
do{
    System.out.println("Enter new password.");
    password = kb.nextLine();
}while(passwordList.contains(password));
```

Please note, you need to import -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Comment: "...ensuring that none of these common passwords are **contained** within **the users password**". You are checking if a password is contained in the list instead. By the way, the initial assignment of `""` is spurious.

Comment: From OP, my understanding is that the OP has pre-determined list of passwords and requirement is to ask user to enter a new password, if the entered password is one of passwords in the pre-determined list.

Comment: Tried this, however the program skips the part in which the user is expected to input the new password.

Comment: when you say "skips", what is actually happening? I am assuming that you have initialized the commonPassword

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
@Test
public void test(){

    String password = "dfsdf";
    String[] commonPass= new String[] {"bla", "blu", "blo", "bly", "ble", "bli"};

    for(int i = 0; i < commonPass.length; i++) 
    {
      if (password.equalsIgnoreCase(commonPass[i])) 
      {
        System.out.println("Enter new password.");

      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

u want to match passwords so use .equals why u using indexOf.

Comment: OP is checking to see if a common password is located anywhere within the possible user password.

Comment: To be honest, I did try that but I continued to get errors. I just ran out of patience and decided to try everything.